# php controller function not working

Tags: php, cakephp

I have a controller class in app/controllers/components/pqr.php in which I have defined a mapper function .Code are below :

```
class MapperComponent extends Object 
{
        function startup(&$controller)
    {
        $this->controller =& $controller;
    }


        function get_supplier_map()
        {
        $model=$this->controller->modelNames;

        $q="select id,name from suppliers where delete_status=0";
        $res=$this->controller->$query($q);

        $map=array();

        foreach($res as $val)
        {
                    $map[$val['suppliers']['id']]=$val['suppliers']['name'];
        }

        return $map;
    }
}
```

I am calling the function from another controller class app/controllers/items/abc.php like this :

```
$this->set('supplier_map',$this->Mapper->get_supplier_map());
```

The above code is working in localhost,but not getting anything in live server.

Comment: what is the error coming?

Comment: Fatal Error : Call to Undefined methood MapperComponent ::get_supplier_map()  in .............(file path and line no)

Comment: Please provide your CakePHP version number.